# 8 Queens brute force problem is not printing out the results, C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, chess, brute-force

The 8 queens puzzle is a problem of placing 8 chess queens in each column on a chessboard so that no two queens threaten each other; thus, a solution requires that no two queens share the same row or diagonals. I was given an assignment to solve the 8 queens problem using a 1D array and to use brute force. I know this is very inefficient but this is the assignment and we already solved it using backtracking in the previous assignment. I've come up with the following code but it doesn't print anything. Not sure what the problem is but I am guessing my ok() function, which is supposed to return true if its a legitimate solution, is perhaps not set up correctly to check?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool ok(int b[]){
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        for(int c=0; c<8; c++){ 
            //checks same row, up diagonal, down diagonal for other queens
            if(b[i]==b[c]||(c-i)==abs(b[c]-b[i])) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;//if none of these returned false, then the board is ok and we return true
};//end of ok

void print(int b[], int z){//this method prints out the double array
    cout<<"Solution: " <<z<<endl;
        for(int j =0;j<8;j++){//loop for row
            cout<<b[j];
            cout<<endl;
        }//end of loop for row
    cout<<"Done!"<<endl;
};//end of print

int main()
{
    int board[8];
    int count = 0;
    for(int i0 =0; i0 <8; i0 ++)
        for(int i1 =0; i1 <8; i1 ++)
            for(int i2 =0; i2 <8; i2 ++)
                for(int i3 =0; i3 <8; i3 ++)
                    for(int i4 =0; i4 <8; i4 ++)
                        for(int i5 =0; i5 <8; i5 ++)
                            for(int i6 =0; i6 <8; i6 ++)
                                for(int i7 =0; i7 <8; i7 ++){
                                    board[0]=i0;
                                    board[1]=i1;
                                    board[2]=i2;
                                    board[3]=i3;
                                    board[4]=i4;
                                    board[5]=i5;
                                    board[6]=i6;
                                    board[7]=i7;
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    //used the indices of the loops to set a configuration in array board...
                                    // if this configuration is conflict-free, print the count and the board
                                    if(ok(board)){
                                        print(board, ++count);//prints board if it is ok
                                    }//end if(ok(board)
                                    
                                    //clear/reset the board
                                    board[0]=0;
                                    board[1]=0;
                                    board[2]=0;
                                    board[3]=0;
                                    board[4]=0;
                                    board[5]=0;
                                    board[6]=0;
                                    board[7]=0;
                                }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested your `print` function separately?  Does it work correctly?  Have you verified your `ok` function, separately?  Does it work correctly?

Comment: Write a test for your `ok` function to be sure it works correctly first.

Comment: Passing arrays to functions is a little dicey in C++, although since you know they'll all be length 8 that avoids a lot of the problems it can cause. In any case it looks like your `ok` function will always return `false` (what happens for the very first thing it checks, `i = c = 0`?) so you definitely want to examine its logic closely.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing each queen with itself in the loop inside `ok()`. You can fix it easily like this:

```
bool ok(int b[]){
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        for(int c=i+1; c<8; c++){ // Now c != i
```

This gives correctly the 92 solutions.

If you're too lazy to count, run `./solver | wc -l | sed 's/.$//'` :)

Comment: It's just a dirty hack. Each solution prints 10 lines. -- `print solutions => count lines => remove last character (divide by 10)`

Comment: @Kostas thanks alot dude! I completely overlooked that. This solved my problem